# When to use Synchronisation in web app

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, synchronization

Currently using spring 4.

> Basic flow Controller-> Service -> Some method from custom utils class
>   -> repository -> Some method from custom utils class -> Controller.

**Controller**

```
@Autowired
    GenericService genService;
```

**Service**

```
@Autowired
    private DBUtil dbUtil;
    @Autowired
    WSSDBService wssDBService;
    @Autowired
    LDAPService ldapService;
    @Autowired
    HttpConnService httpConn;
```

**Repository**

```
@Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemp;
```

**Example method in utility class- many such static methods**

```
public static JsonArray toJsonArray(ArrayList<Integer> intlist) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(intlist, new TypeToken<List<String>>() {
        }.getType());
        if (!element.isJsonArray()) {
            // fail appropriately
        }
        JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
        return jsonArray;
    }
```

This application seems to work fine or is it something going on between threads which I am not aware of, like multiple threads accessing a method at same time and sharing same result even though they should not. Or each thread has its own memory space in web app?

What is the worst case when I will face a sync issue?

Or is it I am not going to face any such issue as threads are managed by the container.
If I have to improve and handle such, where should I exactly need to synchronize.

Please suggest.

Comment: You shouldn't keep state in a webapp (or use non-threadsafe shared resources), so the correct answer would be "never synchronize". It's bad for throughput and indicates design flaws.

Comment: So when multiple requests are made to server, say 10 per second, each will be served independently, will they not share the same memory space, even if its static?

Comment: Even if what is static? Do you think that two threads can't execute the same static method at the same time? It's only object state that needs to be avoided, you can't overwrite local variables.

Comment: As given in question static is method, it accepts values and return a result, how this will work in case of multiple threads.

Comment: As I already said, there's nothing that prevents multiple threads from running the same method at the same time. If they access *shared* variables, you have a potential synchronization problem. However your example doesn't have any *shared* variables, so it would run fine.